# NextJS image component doesn't load optmized images

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

I am having problems with NextJS Image component.

At one specific image it seems that the optimization is not working as expected.

I want this image to be responsive (full width with 100vw responsiveness).

All images are static imported.

**Here is the container of the image's CSS (a div):**

```
position: relative !important;
width: 100vw !important;
height: 105vw !important;
object-fit: contain;
max-width: 1600px;
```

**Here is Image component:**

```
<Image
src={/img/thisimage.png}
alt={''}
priority={true}
quality={60}
fill
/>
```

On the network debugging the image downloaded seems to be fixed at the largest size (it is the same behaviour for all screen sizes).
**Here are the requisition details performed to load the image on the browser:**

```
GET
scheme: http
host: localhost:3000
filename: /img/thisimage.webp

HEADERS
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Host: localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/thispage
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0
```

I was expecting that the requisitions at the network were being generated with different params to get especific sizes and qualities for each screen size.

Comment: i think you need to use sizes property on the Image Component.


https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes

Comment: I have already tried that as follows:
          sizes="(min-width: 520px) 400px, (min-width: 340px) calc(87.5vw - 38px), calc(-100vw + 560px)"
          placeholder="blur"
          priority={true}
          quality={80}

The container of the image is on relative position